# How do I get an order collection in admin order view using the email address of the current order?

Tags: magento2, orders, order-email, di

I am trying to build an order history table to display previous orders `(order number/date/items ordered, etc)` from a customer order in the admin order view `(Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Info)`. This table should list all previous orders that used the email from the current order regardless if they are a guest or have an account.

I did this in **Magento 1.9** by calling the model directly in the template and running through the loop for orders and items for those orders:

```
<?php
$orderCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customer_email',$_order->getCustomerEmail())->addFieldToSelect('*')->setOrder('entity_id', 'desc');
$recordNumber = 1;
if ($orderCollection->getSize() >= 2) { 

$orderCollection->getSelect()->limit(20);
foreach($orderCollection as $order){
$history_id = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($order->getIncrementId())->getId();
$orders = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->load($order->getId()); 
$orderHistoryDate = $this->formatDate($order->getCreatedAtStoreDate(), 'medium', true);
$items = $orders->getAllVisibleItems();

//list orders (order number, date, status)

foreach($items as $item):

//list items in orders (qty ordered, item name, sku)

endforeach;

}
}
```

How can I do this with dependency injection on **Magento 2**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I ended up solving this:

**app/code/WSS/OrderHistory/registration.php**

```
<?php \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'WSS_OrderHistory',
__DIR__
);
```

**app/code/WSS/OrderHistory/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Info">
        <plugin name="customer_order_history" type="WSS\OrderHistory\Plugin\Block\Adminhtml\OrderHistory" sortOrder="15"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**app/code/WSS/OrderHistory/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="WSS_OrderHistory" setup_version="0.0.1">
</module>
</config>
```

**app/code/WSS/OrderHistory/Plugin/Block/Adminhtml/OrderHistory.php**

```
<?php

namespace WSS\OrderHistory\Plugin\Block\Adminhtml;

class OrderHistory extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
protected $_orderCollectionFactory;
        
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
    \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,
    array $data = []
)
{
    $this->_orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

public function getOrderCollection($email) 
{
    $collection = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                    ->addFieldToFilter('customer_email', $email)
            ->setOrder('entity_id','desc');
    return $collection;
}
}
```

**app/code/WSS/OrderHistory/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
<referenceBlock name="order_additional_info">
        <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Template" name="custom_block" template="WSS_OrderHistory::order/view/history.phtml" />
</referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**app/code/WSS/OrderHistory/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/history.phtml**

```
<?php 
$currentOrder = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('\Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Info')->getOrder(); 
$historyBlock = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('WSS\OrderHistory\Plugin\Block\Adminhtml\OrderHistory'); 
$currentEmail = $currentOrder->getCustomerEmail();
$orderCollection = $historyBlock->getOrderCollection($currentEmail);
if ($orderCollection->getSize() >= 2) { 
?>
<section class="admin__page-section">
<div class="admin__page-section-title">
<span class="title"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Order History / ') ?>
<?php 
if ($orderCollection->getSize() > 20) echo 'Last 20 Orders (';
echo $orderCollection->getSize() . ' Total';
if ($orderCollection->getSize() > 20) echo ')';
?></span>
</div>
<div class="admin__page-section-content">
<?php 
echo '<div class="fieldset">';
echo '<dl>';
//orders
$orderCollection->getSelect()->limit(20);
foreach($orderCollection as $order){
    $history_id = $order->getEntityId();
    $orderHistoryDate = $order->getCreatedAt();
    $items = $order->getItemsCollection();
    
    echo '<dt>' . $orderHistoryDate . ' (Order#: <a href="' . $this->getUrl('sales/order/view', array('order_id' => $history_id)) .  '">' . ltrim(ltrim($order->getIncrementId(),"1"),"0") . '</a>) [Status: <span>' . $order->getStatus() . '</span>]</dt>';
    // items
    foreach($items as $item):
        echo '<dd>' . round($item->getQtyOrdered(), 0) . 'x - ' . $item->getName() . ' (Part#: <a href="' . $item->getProduct()->getProductUrl() . '" target="_blank">' . $item->getSku() . '</a>)</dd>';
    endforeach;
}
?>
</div>
</section>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add dependency injection like this :

```
protected $order;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->order = $order;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
```

and get collection like:

```
$orderCollection = $this->order->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customer_email',$_order->getCustomerEmail())->addFieldToSelect('*')->setOrder('entity_id', 'desc');
$recordNumber = 1;
if ($orderCollection->getSize() >= 2) { 

$orderCollection->getSelect()->limit(20);
foreach($orderCollection as $order){
$history_id = $this->order->loadByIncrementId($order->getIncrementId())->getId();
$orders = $this->order->load($order->getId()); 
$orderHistoryDate = $this->formatDate($order->getCreatedAtStoreDate(), 'medium', true);
$items = $orders->getAllVisibleItems();

//list orders (order number, date, status)

foreach($items as $item):

//list items in orders (qty ordered, item name, sku)

endforeach;
```

Comment: I could not get this to work for me, the function kept throwing errors due to missing elements